# Should questions be constrained to only one move?

Tags: discussion

I've seen examples of it in the past also, but just a while ago, this [one](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44687/migration-weirdness-so-su-so-sf-su) reminded me specifically of that behaviour: *a question is asked, after a few minutes it is moved to another site, ... after some more it is moved again to another ...*

Now, to people who have nothing better to do (*and I ask them not to misunderstand this, but I've no other way of putting it*) this *game* can be somewhat fun, but to the ones that asked the original question, and then maybe closed the browser (*meaning, they'll have to go looking for it later on*) it can be a pain to find it again.

***So, I ask you, should questions be restricted to moving only once ?*** (a raise in votes to move it also comes to mind).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No. What if a Super User question is wrongly migrated to Server Fault, and because of this restriction is closed as off topic. Will the original poster be happier than if it had been migrated to Super User and possibly answered?

The migration of questions is not a matter of *fun*, but rather a matter of finding the best possible community for that question to be answered. Migrations are better than closes for the original poster, always.

Comment: +a for posting the most rational answer. That doesn't mean I agree with it wholly, but I understand your point.

Answer (score 1):

No, far too many sysadmin questions are migrated to SU.

Comment: And opposite. Many SO users are still in the "IT related => serverfault" bad tradition.

Answer (score 1):

I've long wanted to post a question:

> If you see this question, please do the following:
>
> - If it's open on SO, please migrate to SF
> - If it's open on SF, please migrate to SU
> - If it's open on SU, please migrate to SO

But I'm pretty sure fewer people would play the game than those that would close it, or even mark it as abusive.

Except maybe on SF - where more people have dealt with mail system configuration and might get more of a chuckle (or reminder of their PTSD) out of it than elsewhere.

Comment: The day has come for such frivolity, no?

Comment: ...but i could only play on one site... :(  (and i couldn't play very well there, now, could i?)

Comment: @quack - Welcome to the Hotel Metafornia!

Answer (score 0):

Programmers aren't always right, sometimes something will get moved to the wrong site.  We need to have a way to fix that.

Comment: Well, why don't they think before voting then ?

Comment: @Idigas: Maybe they have nothing better to do.

Comment: @Idigas: the SO community isn't always the best at deciding whether a question belongs on SU or SF; they just know it doesn't belong on SO.  many questions are migrated to SU that are not on topic there, and the 3k+ users and mods have to catch them and vote them closed (or migrated to SF, or, very rarely, back to SO).